# Some control properties in WPF is text field?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am new to WPF and I find some properties of control is in text field instead of combobox in winform. For example : the columnwidth property of datagrid. I don't know why MS add this feature ? What is the advantage of it ? it makes developers harder to set the property value since we don't know what we should type in there.

Comment: Hi Robert Levy, I want to know what is the advantage of this new feature. Why MS add it to wpf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF enables more flexibility.  In addition to the old fashioned option of specifying width in pixels, you get other options.  See here for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridlength(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: I still don't find it more advantage than the old fashioned option. If they want to allow developer to specify a fixed value just add a "custom" column to combobox and a "custom length" field which allow us to enter a value. I mean something similar to custom cell format in winform design.